# Setting EF to work with Castle Windsor

Tags: entity-framework, castle-windsor

I have set up my project to work with Entity Framework. It is a database first approach.

For the IoC, I am using Castle Windsor and the project is set up to inject all the dependencies.
My question is, is there a need to set up Castle to do the same for my EF entity? How can I do that?

Comment: Are you asking if you shouls register your dao entity objects into castle container? Short answer is no you shouldnt need it, why would you?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to use Entity Framework with Castle. I would suggest that you adopt both the [Unit of Work](http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article122.aspx) and [Repository](http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/) patterns. The DbContext provides most of the functionality for a unit of work, and DbSet similarly provides most of what is needed for a repository.

The main issue you will run into is that EF doesn't understand dependency injection for model objects. EF always uses the empty constructor when it allocates a model object, and this means we don't get the opportunity to do dependency injection into model objects. We have gotten around this by using the object materialization hook on the DbContext:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += EFObjectLoadInitializer;
```

The EFObjectLoadInitializer then injects the Kernel into the model object (all our model objects must support the IInjectKernel interface). Upon injection, the Kernel is then used to resolve any other dependencies. Its not very clean, but it works well and allows us to leverage off of the rest of the infrastructure that we have set up with Windsor.